# Почему роутер работает только в одном компоненте?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

Есть файл index.js, в нём вложен компонент App. В App находится роутер.

**App.js**:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from './components/Menu/Menu';
import Burger from "./components/Burger/Burger";
import Order from "./components/Order/Order";

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const pathBurger = ["/hamburger", "/cheeseburger", "/chickenburger", "/fishburger"]
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Menu}/>
                    <Route path={pathBurger} component={Burger}/>
                    <Route path='/order' component={Order}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**index.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import configureStore, {history} from "./redux/stores/configureStore"
import App from './App';
import {ConnectedRouter} from "connected-react-router";
import './index.css'

const store = configureStore();

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App/>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Хочу, например, сделать роутер в компоненте **Burger**, например, следующим образом:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import BurgerIngredients from "./BurgerIngredients/BurgerIngredients";
import "./Burger.css"
import BurgerInfo from "../BurgerInfo/BurgerInfo";
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";
import OrderCompletion from "../Order/OrderCompletion/OrderCompletion";

export default class Burger extends Component {
    render() {

        // burgerId будет равен одному из следующих значений
        // "/hamburger", "/cheeseburger", "/chickenburger", "/fishburger"
        const burgerId = this.props.match.url;

        return (

            <div className="Burger">
                <BurgerInfo name={burgerId}/>

                <Route path={this.props.match.url} component={BurgerIngredients}/>
                <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/order'} component={OrderCompletion}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

В результате страница по адресам "/hamburger", "/cheeseburger", "/chickenburger", "/fishburger" не отображается. Просто белый экран мне показывает. Кстати, я допускаю, что в коде выше ошибка у меня не одна.

Можно ли роутинг делать не только в компоненте App, а и в других компонентах? Наверняка же можно, поскольку это позволит делать приложение более гибким. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему рендеринг компонента Burger не происходил?
В нём я пытался пользовался теми свойствами this, которых не существовало.
Сейчас всё работает, белые экраны не появляются, а каждый Link меняет состояние приложения в соответствии с заданием

Answer (score 0):

Оберните ваши руты в дочернем компоненте Burger в `<Switch>`. Но такой код может работать с побочными эффектами, нужно учитывать это. Руты внутри дочерних компонентов называются *"унаследованными"*. Относительно белого экрана, если рутер не может сопоставить путь, то `Route` ничего не рендерит и Вы получаете белый экран. Если бы была ошибка - то в консоли она бы вылезла.

Также, чтобы в `props` попал `match`, `location` и `history` - нужно обернуть компонент в [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md), он также находится в `react-router-dom` пакете. То есть нужно переписать компонент вот так:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import BurgerIngredients from "./BurgerIngredients/BurgerIngredients";
import BurgerInfo from "../BurgerInfo/BurgerInfo";
import OrderCompletion from "../Order/OrderCompletion/OrderCompletion";

import "./Burger.css"

class Burger extends Component {
  render() {

    // burgerId будет равен одному из следующих значений
    // "/hamburger", "/cheeseburger", "/chickenburger", "/fishburger"
    const burgerId = this.props.match.url;

    return (
      <div className="Burger">
        <BurgerInfo name={burgerId}/>
        <Switch>  
          <Route path={this.props.match.url} component={BurgerIngredients}/>
          <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/order'} component={OrderCompletion}/>
        </Switch> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Burger);
```

Comment: К сожалению, Ваше решение не работает. Но за наводку про withRouter и про то почему появляется белый экран спасибо.

Comment: @Kniga что именно у Вас не работает? Если с моим решением у Вас по прежнему белый экран, то ставьте `debugger` в рендеринге `Burger` компонента и смотрите что у Вас приходит в `url` и вообще доходите ли Вы до него.